# The reasons of this unexpected terminated event, Omnet++ was terminated automatically after about 20 seconds of IDE loading

Tags: omnet++

When I run the Omnet++, and the IDE of it is loaded completely, after about 20 seconds, the Omnet++ IDE and the Omnet++ are terminated automatically.
What are the possible reasons for this unwanted phenomenon?
The Omnet++ is installed on Ubuntu LTS 22 in the virtual state by the VirtualBox.
Thanks in advance

Error Log :

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f5970257bd2, pid=2831, tid=3159
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.1+12 (17.0.1+12) (build 17.0.1+12)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.1+12 (17.0.1+12, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x7fbd2]  fread+0x22
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E" (or dumping to /home/maryam/core.2831)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/maryam/hs_err_pid2831.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

[image: Status screenshot after running the Omnet++ 6]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the IDE just disappears without any interaction or error report, the most likely cause is that your VM is configured with very low amount of memory and the *omkiller* kills the IDE process because of low memory conditions.

Comment: As you say, it probably terminates unexpectedly due to lack of hardware resources, because no clear reason can be found for it. I have allocated 6 GB of memory and 2 processors for it by the VirtualBox to its virtual machine. What should be the minimum required hardware resources?